# DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() is not returning all files on desktop(it excludes shortcuts)

Tags: c#, .net, directoryinfo, getfiles

I have a listBox1 that should display all the files on my desktop, i have used the following method to do so

```
string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
DirectoryInfo path = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

foreach (var file in path.GetFiles())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("File : " + file.Name);
}
```

It works but for some reason it doesn't display some shortcuts, it displays a few shortcuts but most of them are not displayed. I have no idea why this is happening

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @asawyer implied question is "why is this happening?"

Comment: Can you give us an example of a shortcut that *does* display in this list vs *doesn't*?

Comment: It will, extension would be `.lnk`

Comment: My fist guess is that there are shortcuts in the "All Users" desktop as well.

Comment: What files aren't being displayed?  If you open a command prompt and navigate to the Desktop directory, what does `dir` output?  If `GetFiles` is returning some shortcuts but not everything displayed on your desktop, my initial feeling would be that the Windows shell aggregates files from the Desktop directory with some other settings to create the display - i.e., the display might show things that aren't in the Desktop directory.

Comment: Did you try `info.GetFileSystemInfos` ? I think that returns everything.

Comment: @Dialecticus Sure I can read between the lines, but I don't come to SO to play 20 questions. John Please take the time to write clear concise questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably missing the shortcuts in the "All Users" desktop:

```
string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
DirectoryInfo path = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

foreach (var file in path.GetFiles())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("File : " + file.Name);
}

//  Get files in the "common" desktop
filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory);
path = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

foreach (var file in path.GetFiles())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("File : " + file.Name);
}
```

You can refactor to combine the common code if that works.

Comment: This works, i never knew that the desktop was being manipulated by the "all users desktop" . Thank you